# Transfer data from remote server database into local database daily

Tags: .net, database, web-services, synchronization

I have access to (to-be-developed) web service that can return data from a remote database.

The consumer for the data is a Windows/.NET application that needs to insert that data into the local database (not necessarily SQL Server).

This syncing is one-way only -> from server to local database. Local database however can have more data (inserted locally through the .NET application) than the server database.

How can I achieve that kind of data transfer? Some specific questions I have now:

- What type of data should the web service return ?
- How to ask only the data from the web service that is not
  already found in the local database ?

Comment: As for only data not already in local database.   One way is a timestamp.  The web service would need to know what data has changed since a time stamp to send.  With a data set you would get the current time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

You should use windows services to perform above task . You can schedule windows service to run once in a day to import data from remote database server to local server.

You have to write your own logic to determine which data is present at local database and than  import the data which is not present in local data store. You have to  write all this logic in wndows service only.

Answer (score 0):

1)You can have windows service or console application better is to go with windows service for following reasons:-

- A Windows Service will run even if a user is not logged into the PC (will run even if the server is sitting at the login prompt) (***Note - this may depend on the version of Windows you are running).
- A service can run as high-authority accounts such as Network Service or Local System, or a User - they have more configurability in that regard
- A service also comes built in with options for starting, stopping, restarting, and pausing while running (sometimes)
- You can also set up failure conditions for services, like if it fails have it auto-restart.

2)Dataset or DataTable is what you need(After filtering all the data on server) so that all you have to do is insert the record in destination database/databases.

3)As far as filtering condition is concerned you can have it configured as per your convenience, I will prefer executing it once a day(At day end) and insert all records of that day.